# Can't draw an image on a canvas using Image(ImageResource)

Tags: gwt

I've run into an issue where Context2d.drawImage doesn't work when the image is constructed using Image(ImageResource). But it does work when Image(String) is used.

It looks like a GWT bug, so I've filed a bug report here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8180

Does anyone have some insight why this doesn't work? It seems like a serious bug to me, but I couldn't find it in the GWT issue tracker or here on StackOverflow. Since I'm new to GWT, would appreciate your comments on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that in all GWT version up to 2.5.1, an `Image` created form an `ImageResource` uses a transparent GIF and shows the `ImageResource` image as a background image (through CSS). This will be fixed in GWT 2.6 ([the fix is already in *master*](https://gwt-review.googlesource.com/2110))